# Evaluate inner product of bra and ket in Sympy Quantum

Tags: python, state, sympy, orthogonal

In sympy I have defined a two kets and a corresponding bra, when I apply the bra to the kets...

```
from sympy import sqrt
from sympy.physics.quantum import Bra,Ket,qapply
superpos = (Ket('Dead')+Ket('Alive'))/sqrt(2)
d = qapply(Bra('Dead')*superpos)
```

...I get this result:

```
sqrt(2)*<Dead|Alive>/2 + sqrt(2)*<Dead|Dead>/2
```

How do I set 'Dead' and 'Alive' as orthogonal states, so that `d.doit()` gives `sqrt(2)/2`?

So far I've only been able to substitute the brakets by hand:

```
d.subs(Bra('Dead')*Ket('Dead'),1).subs(Bra('Dead')*Ket('Alive'),0)
```

But how do I make the brakets evaluate automatically? Why doesn't the `InnerProduct` result to 1 for identical brakets and 0 for brakets with different labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that [InnerProduct](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/innerproduct.html) doesn't know how to evaluate these values and so leaves the unsimplified expression instead.  Looking at the [source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/physics/quantum/innerproduct.py#L126), I see that it tries to call `_eval_innerproduct()` on the `Ket`, which says this.

```
def _eval_innerproduct(self, bra, **hints):
    """Evaluate the inner product betweeen this ket and a bra.

    This is called to compute <bra|ket>, where the ket is ``self``.

    This method will dispatch to sub-methods having the format::

        ``def _eval_innerproduct_BraClass(self, **hints):``

    Subclasses should define these methods (one for each BraClass) to
    teach the ket how to take inner products with bras.
    """
```

You should therefore be able to solve your problem by creating 2 new `Bra` classes and a new `Ket` class that implements 2 methods - one to evaluate each of the inner products (using the naming convention mandated above).

For completeness you probably also want to implement the other `Ket` for your orthogonal state and to make sure that `dual_class` returns the right class in each case.

Comment: That's it ! I copy/paste boson.py rename it to OrthogonalBra/OrthogonalKet and change innerproduct to `    def _eval_innerproduct_OrthogonalBra(self, bra, **hints):
        if self.n == bra.n:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but you can use `Qubit` to create orthogonal states.

```
from sympy import sqrt
from sympy.physics.quantum import Dagger, qapply
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import Qubit

dead = Qubit(0)
alive = Qubit(1)
```

These create `Ket(0)` and `Ket(1)`. To make the Bra, you can use the `Dagger` function.

```
print(Dagger(dead) * dead)
<0|0>
```

When applied to your problem:

```
superpos = (dead + alive) / sqrt(2)
d = qapply(Dagger(dead) * superpos)

print(d)
sqrt(2)/2
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately, I am looking for a more general solution : N-dimension basis as with `qutip` (for instance: `from qutip import *` `ket_i=basis(N,i)` )

Answer (score 1):

As Peter points out in his answer, you need to implement a new Bra and Ket class yourself. This is a nice general implementation for orthogonal states that you can use.

Example usage:

```py
>>> OrthogonalBra(n)*OrthogonalKet(n)
1
>>> OrthogonalBra(n)*OrthogonalKet(n+1)
0
>>> OrthogonalBra(n)*OrthogonalKet(m)
<n|m>
```

Implementation:

```py
class OrthogonalKet(Ket):

    @classmethod
    def dual_class(self):
        return OrthogonalBra

    def _eval_innerproduct(self, bra, **hints):

        if len(self.args) != len(bra.args):
            raise ValueError('Cannot multiply a ket that has a different number of labels.')

        for i in range(len(self.args)):
            diff = self.args[i] - bra.args[i]
            diff.simplify()

            if diff.is_nonzero:
                return 0

            if not diff.is_zero:
                return None

        return 1


class OrthogonalBra(Bra):

    @classmethod
    def dual_class(self):
        return OrthogonalKet
```

Comment: Relevant PR on the sympy project [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18182).

Comment: Thanks, this looks wonderful! But I guess there hasn't been a release which includes it yet. I could get this working by copy pasting the definition into my own code, but I had to include a `.doit()` call to get it to actually evaluate the inner products. Without that I was still getting the <n|n> notation.

Comment: Yes, you can call either `expr.doit()` or `qapply(expr)` on the expression, similar to some other operations in the QM module.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `expression.xreplace()` is what you are looking for? According to [this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=KAvNCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=orthogonal%20sympy&source=bl&ots=n91HdqYfZN&sig=4ONyE49JUgl25kdLaxj46o-JpOY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPloC6_5nTAhVGfhoKHTqICHUQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=orthogonal%20sympy&f=false) the `xreplace` function can take a dictionary where sympy-symbols or expressions are hashable keys. This would still be clunky like this:

```
from sympy import sqrt
from sympy.physics.quantum import Bra,Ket,qapply
superpos = (Ket('Dead')+Ket('Alive'))/sqrt(2)
d = qapply(Bra('Dead')*superpos)

mySubs = {Bra('Dead')*Ket('Dead'): 1,  Bra('Dead')*Ket('Alive'): 0} ##plus other bindings
d.xreplace(mySubs)
```

(caution: did not yet test it...)

This at least gives you the option to define all the desired substitutions in one place and "reuse" them wherever you like.

Comment: This is basically the same kind of substitution as in the question. I want to perform the innerproduct automatically as with: `sympy.Matrix([1,0,0]).dot(sympy.Matrix([0,1,0]))`

Answer (score 0):

An answer in Fock space:

```
>>> from sympy import sqrt
>>> from sympy.physics.quantum import Dagger,qapply
>>> from sympy.physics.quantum.boson import BosonFockKet
>>> ket_Dead = BosonFockKet(0)
>>> ket_Alive = BosonFockKet(1)
>>> superpos = (ket_Dead+ket_Alive)/sqrt(2)
>>> bra_Dead = Dagger(ket_Dead)
>>> qapply(bra_Dead*superpos).doit()
sqrt(2)/2
```

Is the same thing possible in Hilbert space ?